# Implementing generics on top of non-generic classes

Tags: c#, generics

I have two non-generic classes generated by Entity Framework:

```
    public partial class Event
    {
        public Event()
        {
            this.Notifications = new HashSet<Notification>();
        }

        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public string Description { get; private set; }

        internal virtual ICollection<Notification> Notifications { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract partial class Notification
    {
        private System.Guid Id { get; set; }

        public abstract void Deliver(object eventContext);
    }
```

The implementations of void Deliver(object eventContext) don't require a specific type passed in (they use reflection to extract information from the eventContext), but at the same time, I want the users of the class to be forced to provide a specific type.  To accomplish this, I've decided it would be best to implement a generic layer on top of these classes:

```
public class Notification<TContext>
{
    private Notification internalNotification;

    public Notification(Notification notification)
    {
        if (notification == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("notification");

        this.internalNotification = notification;
    }

    public void Deliver(TContext context)
    {
        this.internalNotification.Deliver(context);
    }
}

public class Event<TContext> : Event
{
    private Event internalEvent;

    internal Event(Event evt)
    {
        if (evt == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("evt");

        this.internalEvent = evt;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Notification<TContext>> GetNotifications()
    {
        foreach (var notification in internalEvent.Notifications)
            yield return new Notification<TContext>(notification);
    }
}
```

This way, I can create code similar to this:

```
public static class Events
{
     public static Event<PaymentContext> PaymentEvent()
     {
        ... get Event object from EF...

        return new Event<PaymentContext>(event);
     }

     public static Event<HireContext> EmployeeHiredEvent()
     {
          .... get Event object from EF...

          return new Event<HireContext>(event);
     }
}
```

Then the users will be forced to pass in the appropriate type to the Deliver(TContext) method.

This works for my situation, but I don't like the way that my generic Notification and Event classes are composed of the non-generic classes - it feels to me as though they should inherit from the non-generic versions instead.  But of course, the entities received from entity framework are of the base class, not the derived generic classes, so some sort of conversion would be required to convert it to the base class (ideally, I'd love to just cast it to the subtype, but I don't think this is possible).

Is there a better way of implementing this "generic layer upon non-generic classes" solution.

Comment: Congratulations, you've discovered why having an external tool generate partial classes for you is not a great idea. :)  
I don't know much about EF, but see if you can make it either generate the methods with a more type-safe signature, or alternatively make it use your generic subclasses instead of these bases.